# Registered Post Type Isn't Showing in Admin Menu

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

I have a custom function to make posts hierarchical by registering a post type in my `functions.php` like this:

```
register_post_type( 'post', array(
    'hierarchical' => true
) );
```

After uploading, the posts item from admin menu just disappears. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

found solution to add argument `public => true`